Notion API to POST Url to Notion Database
I am trying to use Notion API with Apple Shortcuts to send URL from share sheet to Notion Database as a form of URL. I have tried to edit the json request to have "type": "url" and "content": to be the url from share sheet. I need advise on how to correct the code and make the POST request successful. Please forgive me if I am not providing all of the necessary information. Here is my code to do POST to api.notion.com/v1/pages and the attached image is what I have setup for the shortcut. Please, any help would be helpful


{
  "parent": {
    "type": "database_id",
    "database_id": "I HAVE MY REAL DATABASE ID HERE"
   },
   "properties": {
     "URL": {
        "type": "url",
        "title": [
          {
            "type": "url",
            "title": {
               "content": "This is a link to the topmost action of attached apple shortcut flow"
           }
    }
   ]
  }

 }
}




